# How to make my data grid to be loaded super fast?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have to edit my last question to the one bellow as I have found out that the only way for me is to generate the grid using jQuery on ajax function success, I am able to generate the data in the grid but I am not able to figure out how to paginate them, I was trying to find out any useful tutorial to teach me A to Z how to filter the out put in to pages using pagination in a efficient way, All I found on the web was advertisements of data grid plugins or many useless pre-made static grids that won't be modified.

So I am wondering if is that it? Isn't there any A to Z data grid generate tutorial on the web? Is my the only way is to buy one of those made ones?

I would like to make the grid myself as the one attached,

What you see in attached is just a picture of what I want, it's not responsive.

Please help me,I am not a professional, learning all by myself.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: From what I saw you are paginating using jquery after all records are loaded, thats an expensive approach in terms of performance, since you are using ajax you might want to send parameters to paginate it at the moment you process the query, check your table plugin for "lazy loading" and see if it fits your needs

Comment: I'll try lazy loading, thanks